# Query latest insert data of X type before latest insert data of Y type MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a simple data as

```
'crossType' [1-8] | 'isLocal' [1-2] | 'dayCross' [int] | TIMESTAMP
```

I want to find latest insert data of `'isLocal' = 1` before latest insert data of `'crossType' = 2` then my output is `'dayCross'`

Such as

```
'crossType' [1-8] | 'isLocal' [1-2] | 'dayCross' [int] | TIMESTAMP

         1        |        1        |         3        | xx:xx:xxxx
         2        |        2        |         5        | xx:xx:xxxx
         5        |        2        |         7        | xx:xx:xxxx
         3        |        1        |         9        | xx:xx:xxxx
         2        |        1        |         10       | xx:xx:xxxx
```

Latest insert data of 'crossType' = 2 is

```
         2        |        2        |         5        | xx:xx:xxxx
```

Then latest insert data of 'isLocal' = 1

```
         3        |        1        |         9        | xx:xx:xxxx
```

And my output will be **9**

What is the Query statement for this problem.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
select dayCross
from your_table
where isLocal = 1
and timestamp < ( select max(timestamp)
                    from your_table
                    where crossType = 2
                )
order by timestamp desc
limit 1;
```

Outer query will return latest `dayCross` whose `timestamp` is before the latest `timestamp` for `crossType` 2 (found in the subquery).

Comment: You can just use `SELECT MAX(timestamp)` in the subquery.

Answer (score 0):

Here is you query:

```
SELECT dayCross FROM testing.new_table
    WHERE isLocal='1' AND `timestamp` <
        (select max(`timestamp`) from testing.new_table where crossType='2')
    ORDER BY `timestamp` DESC LIMIT 1;
```

You get latest inserted dayCross with 'isLocal' = 1 from data before the latest inserted with 'crossType' = 2.

Here is the data:

```
 crossType    isLocal     dayCross    timestamp
    1            1            3    2017-02-04 00:50:00
    2            2            5    2017-02-04 00:40:00
    5            2            7    2017-02-04 00:30:00
    3            1            9    2017-02-04 00:20:00
    2            1           10    2017-02-04 00:10:00
```